# Searching over multiple ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having difficulty forming the appropriate ActiveRecord query to search Kitchens, which have a city field, and Meals, which have a date field.

```
class Kitchen < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :meals, through: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :kitchen
  has_many :meals
end

class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :kitchen, to: :user
end
```

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
date = Date.new(params[:date][:year].to_i, params[:date][:month].to_i, params[:date][:day].to_i)
@meals = Meal.where(meal_date: date)
@meals.reject { |meal| meal.kitchen.city.downcase != params[:city].downcase }
```

Comment: Hello fellow Launcher!  meal and kitchen have no association so `meal.kitchen` will blow up.  Is there a relation there?

Comment: Hey there, friend! Which cohort did you graduate from? I launched Fall 2013.

Comment: I updated my code. I was missing associations.

Comment: You will not be able to use `Kitchen` in your query if you use delegates.  The delegates method does not notify ActiveRecord of any associations.

Comment: Ah, thank you. It sounds like I need to add 'belongs_to :kitchen' to my Meal model, and create a migration to store the kitchen_id on the meals table in order to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Anthony pointed out you need to add an association between Meal and Kitchen, then you should be able to make queries against `Meal` based on the city of the `Kitchen`.

```
class Kitchen < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :meals
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :kitchen
    has_many :meals
end

class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :kitchen
end
```

For example, something like:

```
Meal.joins(:kitchen).where(meal_date: date, kitchen: {city != params[:city]})
```

See [Conditions on Joined Tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) for more information.